# Find the different value in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that I would like to return only the different value. Ex.:

```
Array
(
    [555] => Array
        (
            [123] => 2017-02-04 00:00:00
            [124] => 2017-02-04 00:00:00
            [125] => 2017-08-31 14:59:59
            [126] => 2017-02-04 00:00:00
            [127] => 2017-02-04 00:00:00
        )

)
```

I would like to get only the item:

```
[125] => 2017-08-31 14:59:59
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand why this is a multidimensional problem? How does the `222` array come into play?

Comment: @domdom I adjusted the text.

Comment: [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) would be one option, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, check the [live demo](https://eval.in/804842)

```
$count = array_count_values($array[555]);
asort($count);     //sort according the times of value. 
print_r([array_search(key($count), $array[555]) => key($count)]);
```

Comment: That's roughly how I would've done it too. Always nice to add a tiny bit of explanation though (even if it might be obvious to us).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


$test =Array
(
    555 => Array
    (
        123 => '2017-02-04 00:00:00',
        124 => '2017-02-04 00:00:00',
        125 => '2017-08-31 14:59:59',
        126 => '2017-02-04 00:00:00',
        127 => '2017-02-04 00:00:00'
    )

);
foreach ($test as $k => $v) {
    $res = array_count_values($v);
}
$fin = '';
foreach ($res as $k => $v) {
    if ($v == 1) {
        $fin = $k;
    }
}
print_r($fin);
```